# Enabling Session resumption in node/sails js

Tags: node.js, ssl, sails.js

I have been working on improving the ssllabs rating of a node/sails.js based website but I am not being able to enable session resumption. So far the information I am getting is `IDs assigned but not accepted`.

I found some information on how to do that in a express node.js app [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/3132) but I am not sure where this code should run in a sails.js framework or where sails does the `var server = tls.createServer();`.

Should it be in the middleware?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found how to do it.
In the http.js file I just did:

```
customMiddleware: function(app) {
console.log("config of Middleware is called");
//session resumption/reuse enabled
var server = sails.hooks.http.server;
var tlsSessionStore = {};

server.on("newSession", function (id, data, cb) {
  tlsSessionStore[id.toString("hex")] = data;
  cb();
});

server.on("resumeSession", function (id, cb) {
  var tlsSessionId = id.toString("hex");
  cb(null, (tlsSessionId in tlsSessionStore) ? tlsSessionStore[tlsSessionId] : null);
});
},
```

And I added the customMiddleware in `order[ ]`.